# Python: distributing video frames over multiple processes

Tags: python, opencv, video, multiprocessing

The goal is to do image processing on video frames. The video can be divided in 16 seperate regions on which the processing can be done. Therefore 16 different processes are used to do the processing concurrently (result is stored per region as well).

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing

def process_region(n):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/path/to/video.avi')

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    while ret:
        # crop frame to region n
        # process the region

        ret, frame = cap.read()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(process_region, range(16))
```

An obvious flaw here is that all processes are all loading the video seperatly. Testing does show that the performance of reading a test video does go down after a certain (10) number of processes:

```
+------------+--------+
| #processes | T (s.) |
+------------+--------+
|      1     |  30.2  |
|      2     |  27.1  |
|      3     |  32.9  |
|      4     |  30.2  |
|      5     |  31.7  |
|      6     |  29.6  |
|      7     |  29.5  |
|      8     |  29.5  |
|      9     |  30.6  |
|     10     |  30.9  |
|     11     |  32.4  |
|     12     |  35.7  |
|     13     |  40.3  |
|     14     |  43.5  |
|     15     |  48.3  |
|     16     |  52.5  |
+------------+--------+
```

I tried using only 1 process to read all video frames and send it with `multiprocessing.Pipe` to 16 started `multiprocessing.Process` processes. This had however the worst performance (> 15 min).

My question is if there would a way to distribute the video frames with better performance than having all processes load the video itself.

Note that this is run on a dual 8-core machine with 64GB of memory.

Comment: Have you investigated threads? (e.g., http://pymotw.com/2/threading/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [numpy-sharedmem](https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem) module to make single images (NumPy arrays in `cv2`) readable by multiple processes. I did exactly this in [one of my projects](https://github.com/vmlaker/sherlock).